# crossdomain.xml not found in ejabberd

Tags: xmpp, cross-domain, ejabberd

I have configured the ejabberd sever but i am not be able to access http://www.example.com:5280/crossdomain.xml

i have set the following parameters in ejabberd.cfg

**Listners**

```
{5280, ejabberd_http, [
                        {access,all},
                         {request_handlers,
                          [
                           {["pub", "archive"], mod_http_fileserver},
                           {["xmpp-http-bind"], mod_http_bind}
                         ]},
%%                       captcha,
                         http_bind,
                         http_poll,
                         register,
                         web_admin
                        ]}
```

**Modules**

```
  {mod_http_fileserver, [
                        {docroot, "/var/log/ejabberd/"},
                        {accesslog, "/var/log/ejabberd/access.log"},
                         {content_types,[{".xml, text/xml"}]}
                      ]},
```

> crossdomain.xml is present at this path in centos "/var/log/ejabberd/"

can anyone help in resolving this issues , i heard that for crossdomain.xml we can also  configure apache webserver , but i don't know how to do that ?

Comment: how did you solve this problem? I am kind of facing something similar, not able to link /crossdomain.xml to the file.. any help?

Comment: People are voting to close this because it is related to server configuration.  If it gets closed, please try serverfault.com!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using Strophe with ejabberd. The crossdomain.xml has nothing to do with ejabberd, it has to do with configuring flash to do cross domain requests.
Of course you don't need flash and it's better to avoid that altogether by means of using a proxy in front. You can use apache or nginx or any other.
[Here](http://anders.conbere.org/blog/2011/05/03/get_xmpp_-_bosh_working_with_ejabberd_firefox_and_strophe/) is a tutorial for nginx.

Comment: if i use apache to set proxy then do i need to query apache webserver for BOSH Service url i.e. http://www.example.com:5280/xmpp-http-bind or ejabber only ?

Comment: Apache would proxy example.com:80/http-bind to example.com:5280/http-bind

Comment: Do yo know how to set it in apache ?

Comment: Have a look at mod_rewrite or mod_proxy depending on what you want to do. There's no learning without effort.